# error expected unqualifed-id before '{' token

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, result, result1, result2, result3, value, cont;
//number user enters/variable
int main()
{
    cout << "please enter the operation,+ for addtion,- for subtaction,* for multiplatcion,/ for division"
    ;cin >> value
    ;cout << "please enter the first number number:";

    cin >> num1
    ;cout << "please enter the second number: ";
    cin >> num2

    ;if(value == '+' )
    ;result = num1 + num2;
    cout << num1 << " plus " << num2 << " is equal to: " << result << ".\n";
    if(value = '-' )
    ;result = num1 - num2;
    cout << num1 << " minus " << num2 << " is equal to: " << result << ".\n";
    if(value = '*' )
    ;result = num1 * num2;
    cout << num1 << " times " << num2 << " is equal to: " << result << ".\n";
    if(value = '/' )
    ;result = num1 / num2;
    cout << num1 << " divided by " << num2 << " is equal to: " << result << ".\n";



}
{
    cout << "press 1 to enter more numbers, or press 0 to not"
    cin >> cont
    if(cont = 1)
    cout << "please enter the operation,+ for addtion,- for subtaction,* for multiplatcion,/ for division"
    cin >> value1
    cout << "please enter the next number:";
    cin num3

    else(cont = 0)

    else(value1 = +)
    ;result1 = result + num3;
    cout << result << " plus " << num3 << " is equal to: " << result1 << ".\n";
    else(value1 = -)
    ;result1 = result - num3
    cout << result << " minus " << num3 << " is equal to: " << result1 << ".\n";
    else(value1 = *)
    ;result1 = result * num3
    cout << result << " times " << num3 << " is equal to: " << result1 << ".\n";
    else(value1 = /)
    ;result1 = result / num3
    cout << result << " divided by " << num3 << " is equal to: " << result1 << ".\n";



}
{
    cout << "press 1 to enter more numbers, or press 0 to not"
    cin >> cont
    if(cont = 1)
    cout << "please enter the operation,+ for addtion,- for subtaction,* for multiplatcion,/ for division"
    cin >> value1
    ;cout << "please enter the next number: ";
    cin >> num4
    else(cont = 0)

    else(value2 = +)
    ;result2 = result1 + num4;
    cout << result1 << " plus " << num4 << " is equal to: " << result2 << ".\n";
    else(value2 = -)
    ;result2 = result1 + num4;
    cout << result << " minus " << num3 << " is equal to: " << result1 << ".\n";
    else(value2 = *)
    ;result2 = result1 * num4
    cout << result << " times " << num3 << " is equal to: " << result1 << ".\n";
    else(value2 = /)
    ;result2 = result1 / num4
    cout << result << " divided by " << num3 << " is equal to: " << result1 << ".\n";





{
    cout << "press 1 to enter more numbers, or press 0 to not"
    cin >> cont
    if(cont = 1)
   cout << "enter the operation,+ for addtion,- for subtaction,* for multiplatcion,/ for division"
    cin >> value2
    ;cout << "please enter the next number: ";
    cin >> num5

    if(value3 = +)
    ;result3 = result2 + num5;
    cout << result2 << " plus " << num5 << " is equal to: " << result3 << ".\n";
    else(value3 = -)
    ;result3 = result2 - num5
    cout << result << " minus " << num3 << " is equal to: " << result1 << ".\n";
    else(value3 = *)
    ;result3 = result2 * num5
    cout << result << " times " << num3 << " is equal to: " << result1 << ".\n";
    else(value3 = /)
    ;result3 = result2 / num5







    return 0;
```

the error happens at line 34, where it says {
so please help me!
the code is for a basic calculator
feel free to use it if you can correct line 34!
I have no idea what is causeing it
I am a noob to the c++
codeing so please help!
I have done my own research and I cannot find it.

Comment: Turn up your warning level as well if you haven't already. This code is buggy and the compiler will warn about it given the chance.

Comment: Try putting `;` at the end of the lines not at the beginning ...

Comment: My God tryin to edit that was a nightmare

Comment: You should start with some basic tutorials or books, as this code looks like nothing I've ever seen.

Comment: @harpun it looks like he might have been getting those `expected ';' before [insert symbol here]` errors.

Comment: You really should start with getting much smaller programs to compile and run properly. And don't use copy and paste. And read a book. Carefully.

Comment: This is one of those few cases where the OP Told us the error message, posted his code, and actually appears to be trying.  Why all the down-votes on this question.  It's actually among the higher-quality questions on this site.

Comment: Missing and extraneous semicolons. Mismatched curly braces. `=` in place of `==`. `else` in place of `else if`. The number of errors may well exceed the number of lines. Delete everything and rewrite from scratch. Start with something much smaller, and get it to compile and run.

Comment: @SamIam While I didn't downvote, I suspect the highly unusual `;` placement made some folks sad...

Comment: I'm honestly curious: Where did you get the idea of putting semicolons at the beginning of lines? It's not illegal (the compiler doesn't care about token placement), but it's a style I've literally never seen before.

Comment: @KeithThompson  have you ever seen a c++ error of the form:  `syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'cout'`?  It looks to me like the OP took that too literally

Comment: A Switch Case Might be your best friend to clean up that code... here is a  Link: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/

Comment: @SamIam: Plausible, but frankly I'm more interested in hearing from the OP.

Answer (score 3):

You can't say stuff like

```
else(value1 = +)
```

in C++. You must mean something else, but it is hard to guess what because there are so many errors in your code. In general, you cannot just type random characters and expect a functioning program.

Answer (score 2):

The error stems from the additional `{ ... }` blocks following the `main` function, since the compiler does not know what to do with code outside of declarations . But that is not the only problem with your code:

- Putting a semicolon directly after an `if` statement means "if the condition is true do nothing anyway", and the next statement is executed either way.
- `if(value = +)` should be `if(value == '+')` etc - you mixed the association `=` with comparison `==`, plus you try using an operator `+` instead of a character `'+'`* what is `else(something)` supposed to do? Code blocks are put in `{}`s, not `()`s

May I suggest you start programming in an easier language like Python? Its meaningful indentation and the lack of semicolons makes life a lot easier...

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of all of the

```
}
{
```

and you'll be able to proceed to fixing your next error.

---

When you write braces like the following: `}`

you're closing your block of code, which in this case is your main function.

and when you write the following: `{`

The compiler thinks that you're trying to start a new function, but there's not function signature and you get an error.

---

It looks to me like you intend all of this code to be inside of your main function, so you want something like the following:

```
int main()
{ 
    //insert all of your code here
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @KeithThompson read the code that the OP has posted.  Does it look like he's using braces in a legal way?

Comment: I deleted my previous comment. Extra braces can be used to introduce new inner scopes, but the OP is not using them correctly. The question has code following the `}` that ends `main`, which is just one of the multiple problems.

Comment: @KeithThompson Do you think that the OP should be using them at all?

Comment: Quick answer: No. Well, they're required at the beginning and end of `main`, and I like to use them for `if` statements, but braces that only introduce a new scope are not needed here.

Comment: @KeithThompson so in that case, would you say that the advice to get rid of those braces: `}{` is valid? particularly where you have a closing brace followed by an opening one?

Comment: I initially thought that the OP had merely added extra matched pairs of braces within `main`, which would be odd but perfectly legal. Then I copy-and-pasted the code and tried compiling it myself, and realized I was mistaken, so I deleted my comment (before I even saw yours). There are multiple serious problems with the code, and yes, the braces are one of them. (A `}` immediately followed by a `{` *can* be valid, but not in this case.)